# Run-Time Errors on userform, need some code reviewing

Tags: excel, printing, runtime-error, userform, type-mismatch

I need some help reviewing some basic code i have, because sometimes it returns the "run-time error", and i'm becoming lost in this. I have a form that have textboxes, when i fill the first, it fills automatically two other textboxes below from a sheet hided on the workbook, it has a combobox that fills automatically with the username of other windows users that also uses this file.
The final objective is print two filled sheets from the textboxes on one row, 2 pages, the printer have both sided property and prints the two sheets on the bothsides of one paper.

```
Private Sub comimprimirvas_prod_Click()
Dim irow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lvalue
lvalue = Now

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Base Dados Vasilhame")

irow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With ws
.Range("A" & irow) = txtclienteopl.Value
.Range("B" & irow) = txtdevolução.Value
.Range("C" & irow) = txtlocaldecarga.Value
.Range("D" & irow) = txtmatricula2.Value
.Range("E" & irow) = txtpistacais.Value
.Range("F" & irow) = txtnºdevolução.Value
.Range("G" & irow) = txtundbarril.Value
.Range("H" & irow) = txtundgrade.Value
.Range("I" & irow) = lvalue

End With

'''''''''''''''''This inserts the username'''''''''''''''''''

Me.ComboBox1.Text = Environ$("Username")

ComboBox1.AddItem "André Lopes"
ComboBox1.AddItem "BackOffice"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Carlos Silva"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Flavio Gonçalves"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Nuno Prada"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Rita Vieira"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Zaida Sousa"
ComboBox1.AddItem ""

txtdevolução.SetFocus


''''''''''''''''This fills sheet Vasilhame''''''''''''''''''

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vasilhame")

.Visible = True
    .Range("AJ7:AL7") = txtclienteopl.Value
    .Range("AJ14:AL14") = txtdevolução
    .Range("AJ9:AL9") = txtlocaldecarga
    .Range("AJ12:AL12") = txtmatricula2
    .Range("AJ16:AL16") = txtpistacais
    .Range("AJ19:AL19") = txtnºdevolução
    .Range("AL21") = txtundbarril
    .Range("AL22") = txtundgrade

End With


''''This fills sheet Devolução de produto'''''''''''''

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Devoluções de produto")

.Visible = True
    .Range("AR9:AY9") = txtnºdevolução.Value
    .Range("AR12:AY12") = txtclienteopl
    .Range("AR15:AY15") = txtmatricula2
    .Range("AR18:AY18") = txtpistacais


End With


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Devoluções de produto", "Vasilhame"))



ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Devoluções de produto", "Vasilhame")).Select

.PrintOut


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Devoluções de produto").Range("AR9:AY9").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Devoluções de produto").Range("AR12:AY12").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Devoluções de produto").Range("AR15:AY15").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Devoluções de produto").Range("AR18:AY18").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vasilhame").Range("AJ7:AL7").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vasilhame").Range("AJ9:AL9").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vasilhame").Range("AJ12:AL12").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vasilhame").Range("AJ14:AL14").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vasilhame").Range("AJ16:AL16").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vasilhame").Range("AJ19:AL19").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vasilhame").Range("AL21").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vasilhame").Range("AL22").ClearContents

txtnºdevolução = ""
txtclienteopl = ""
txtmatricula2 = ""
txtpistacais = ""
txtclienteopl = ""
txtdevolução = ""
txtlocaldecarga = ""
txtmatricula2 = ""
txtpistacais = ""
txtnºdevolução = ""
txtundbarril = ""
txtundgrade = ""

'''''''''''This changes the checkbox to X or blank'''''''''''''''''
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vasilhame").Range("AA2").Value = CheckBox1_PC.Value
CheckBox1_PC.Value = ""


    If CheckBox1_PC.Value = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vasilhame").Range("AA2").Value = "X"
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vasilhame").Range("AA2").Value = ""

    End If


''''''''''''''This changes the checkbox2 to X or blank''''''''''''''
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vasilhame").Range("AG6").Value = CheckBox2_PC.Value
CheckBox2_PC.Value = ""


    If CheckBox2_PC.Value = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vasilhame").Range("AG6").Value = "X"
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vasilhame").Range("AG6").Value = ""

    End If


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vasilhame").Range("AC2:AG2").Value = ComboBox1.Value
ComboBox1.Value = ""

    If ComboBox1.Value = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vasilhame").Range("AC2:AG2").Value = ComboBox1.Value

    End If




.Visible = False

End With

end sub
```

I had some problem on this section, that i dont have always.
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Devoluções de produto", "Vasilhame")).Select"`

Comment: Too much code, focus on the error part and clarify what you mean with *I had some problem on this section, that i dont have always*. You could check first with a loop if those worksheets exist and depending on the result do one thing or other.

Comment: That last code is the error part, i want to print two sheets in two pages at the same time. But it prints at first, at second returns error, at third prints again.

Comment: ````ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Devoluções de produto", "Vasilhame")).Select````

"run-time error 1004"
Select method of sheets class failed

Comment: That means there are no worksheets named like you specied in the array